# Cant access NGINX media folder on browser. Got 404 Not found Error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am having a problem viewing my media folder files on Ubuntu 20.4 NGINX. If I wrote IP address I can see the index page. But if try to access "my_ip/Movies" I got a 404 Not Found error.
pls, check below my default sites-available conf file. I created a symlink with /media/my_server_name/folder_name with /var/www/html

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;


    root /var/www/html;

    
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
    root /var/www/html;

    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /media {
       alias /media;
    }
```

}

Comment: How is the URI `/Movies/` related to `/media/my_server_name/folder_name`? What is the full URI and full path of the file you are trying to access. Show the relavent access log and error log entries.

Comment: My url is like-    " /Movies/Hollywood/2020/ABC/abc.mp4"

Comment: And this file is accessible by Nginx at `/var/www/html/Movies/Hollywood/2020/ABC/abc.mp4`?